# Sending a command in Paramiko as sudo

Tags: command, sudo, paramiko

How can I run a command in a linux box through Paramiko as a sudo user and send the sudo password alomg with it, then get the output?
I tried the following code but since it did not return the output ( I tried testing ls -l /root) I am not sure if it’s working or not.

```
stdin, stdout, stderr =         ssh.exec_command("sudo ls -l")
stdin.write('sudo_password\n')
stdin.flush()
Output = stdout.read.splitlines()
```

A second question is that My understanding is that we cannot ”sudo -s” in the first command and then run the next commands as root while we have used a non-root command to start the session with at first, right?
(Imagine there is no root password on the box)

What is a functional piece of code to send a command as sudo, then provide the password and get the output?

What is a functional code to do the same thing for multiple commands? Can we send the password once and then use the it for the rest of the commands?

Comment: Did you try reading the error output? Does this work from shell? `ssh user@host sudo ls -l`? (as a *single* line)

Comment: Martin! the command you mentioned will return the following:
ssh ubuntu@host sudo ls -l
Password:
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper

Comment: So did you try what it suggests?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

thanks to everyone taking their time and posting their answers.
there is a straightforward answer to this question and here it is:

```
command = 'echo "sudo-password" | sudo <the-command-to-run-as-sudo>'
stdin, stdout, stderr = SESSION.exec_command(command)
stdout = stdout.read().decode()
```

example command:

```
command = 'echo "123456" | sudo ls-l /root'
stdin, stdout, stderr = SESSION.exec_command(command)
stdout = stdout.read().decode()
```

Comment: If you were getting *"a terminal is required to read the password"*, then I cannot imagine how this can work on its own, unless you have changed `sudo` configuration. There's no technical difference between doing `stdin.write('sudo_password\n')` and `echo "sudo-password" | sudo ...`

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` on the target system is configured to require a [terminal emulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) for password prompt.

It suggests you to use `-S` switch to allow password input from the stdin (what you code is attempting to do). So do that.